# how to concat files XML with xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to concat a number 'N' of the XML in another XML.

For example:
I've this XML

```
<BOOKS>
    <BOOK>
        <TITTLE>Lord of the Rings</TITLE>
        <AUTHORS>J. R. R. Tolkien</AUTHORS>
        <AUTHORS>J. K. Rowling</AUTHORS>
        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITTLE>The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies</TITLE>
        <AUTHORS>J. R. R. Tolkien</AUTHORS>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

and this:

```
<BOOKS>
    <BOOK>
        <TITTLE>A Clash of Kings</TITLE>
        <AUTHORS>George R. R. Martin</AUTHORS>
        <AUTHORS>J. K. Rowling</AUTHORS>
        <YEAR>2016</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITTLE>The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies</TITLE>
        <AUTHORS>J. R. R. Tolkien</AUTHORS>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

I need to generate a new file like this:

```
<BOOKS>
    <BOOK>
        <TITTLE>Lord of the Rings</TITLE>
        <AUTHORS>J. R. R. Tolkien</AUTHORS>
        <AUTHORS>J. K. Rowling</AUTHORS>
        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITTLE>The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies</TITLE>
        <AUTHORS>J. R. R. Tolkien</AUTHORS>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITTLE>A Clash of Kings</TITLE>
        <AUTHORS>George R. R. Martin</AUTHORS>
        <AUTHORS>J. K. Rowling</AUTHORS>
        <YEAR>2016</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITTLE>The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies</TITLE>
        <AUTHORS>J. R. R. Tolkien</AUTHORS>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

The XMLs are in my directory: E:\books. I want to concat all files, for example: If I've two files, the script will concat them, but if I've three or more files, the script will concat also. How do I do it?

Comment: What processor are you using? This could easily be done using `collection()` in Saxon (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html).

Comment: What general purpose language (e.g., PHP, Python, Java, C#, VBA) do you have available? As most can walk through folder and process XML using dynamic XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 with Saxon it's

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <BOOKS>
    <xsl:sequence select="collection('dir?select=*.xml')/BOOKS/BOOK"/>
  </BOOKS>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! But I resolved in another way, because I use the framework apache camel and I may to use your functionality